# Mysql slave use more memory than master server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I have used top command to check memory usage on both mysql master and slave server. Master is using only 12% of allotted memory but slave is using 82%. configuration wise both are same. can anyone tell me how to resolve this and why its taking more than slave?

Comment: please add more information about slave and master and there cnf, also server status.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Here is the details which you have asked.                   Master status:

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                    
36694 mysql     20   0 4571028 1.851g   5204 S  17.6 11.8 102090:30 mysqld

Comment: Slave Status:

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                    
28034 mysql     20   0 14.825g 0.013t  11272 S   2.3 83.0   2475:49 mysqld

Comment: Total Memory : 16G
Buffers alloted for both M and S:
key_buffer_size  = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
join_buffer_size        = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 20M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4096
query_cache_size = 200M

Comment: sorry for the delay. did not get chance to check the website. since the slave and master has same amount of resources and shared same cnf into ( memory info). there is one attribute you can add to slave ( I believe its 5.6.x) table_cache (> 4096) this should lower the memory usage

Comment: Ahmed, All the activities are happening at master but it is taking less memory why the slave is taking more. what will happen on slave if i increase table_cache because its taking more memory while reading from master.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 taking more memory than 5.5, so some parameters added as a work around to reduce memory usage . using table cache should help if there is a table(s) called frequently since the server will not get all its information from scratch.

Comment: @Jeevitha: Please add this additional information to you post and dont spread it over your comments. In yor post format your output. with a tt font by identing each line by four blanks so tha this is readable for us.

Comment: Note also that the performance_schema is a memory hog on 5.6 only.  Did you have it turned on?

Answer (score 1):

> query_cache_size = 200M

Too big.  Don't go past 50M, else the maintenance will hurt performance.

> innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G

If you are using InnoDB, set this to 70% of *available* RAM.

`table_open_cache` (formerly called `table_cache`) relates to the number of tables you might need to open, but not the sizes of the tables.  A few hundred is typically enough.  4096 is needed by only a few systems; don't go past that without a clear indication that you need it.

> All the activities are happening at master

If so, what is the Slave for?

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` (on each server) so I can help you dig deeper into your puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem,were we had same mysql configuration on master and slave.

Here it is, i encountered  an issue once when i was checking TOP output for mysqld process and found that the mysqld  memory continuously increasing. Also there was one more thing  that it was using swap memory even if there was enough RAM memory available. we have monitored for a week and this was causing an issue like slow query processing, performance and slowness on DB server.

To solve this problem we have to set correct swappiness

```
To check vm.swappiness:

  cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness    (Default value : 60 (Range 0 to 100))
```

To set a new non-persistent value :

```
   sysctl -w vm.swappiness=0
```

To set a new persistent value :

```
   add vm.swappiness=0 in the /etc/sysctl.conf file
```

All Set !!

Comment: Set that to `1`.  This will avoid being killed by OOM.  Meanwhile, swapping will be minimized.